# Allow for empty values in an array

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am writing a program to read barcodes. I need to read both QR barcodes (with an array) as well as regular barcodes that have one value.

As of now, the code will not accept anything other than QR/Array barcodes.

The program used to accept both barcodes, but would not insert any QR barcode information into the table except Array(0). Whether I scanned a regular barcode (with just the product name) or a QR barcode with many values, only the name would wind up in the table.

I have now edited the SQL INSERT INTO statement to insert all of the QR barcode array values. The problem is that the form where the scan is performed will no longer accept regular barcodes (just the product name).

I tried adding the "OR ''" to account for a possible empty value, but the form will still not accept this.

Here is where I defined the array:

```vb
fValue = Split(Me.txtScanArea.Value, ",")
BCName = fValue(0)
LotNo = fValue(1)
Serial = fValue(2)
Exp = fValue(3)
Weight = fValue(4)
SName = fValue(5)
```

The corresponding SQL statement.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO dbo_ScanLog (Lot, Type, " & _
      "Serial, ScanName, ScanProcess, ScanLot, Expired, " & _
      "Weight, SPN, ScanWarning, Loc, Category, ScanCount, ScanDate) " & _
      "VALUES('" & pbl_Lot & "','" & _
      pbl_Name & "','" & Serial & "' OR '','" & _
      BCName & "',1,'" & LotNo & "' OR '','" & Exp & "' OR '','" & _
      Weight & "' OR '','" & SName & "' OR '','" & _
      msg & "','C','F'," & _
      iCount & ",#" & Now() & "#)"

InsertDB (sql)
```

It will accept a QR barcode (which would read as: ProName,J0801-2019,SN123456,2019.12.25,5,123456,2019.08.01), but not a regular barcode (which would read as: ProName).

When I enter the information for a regular barcode into the Access form, hitting enter will not even attempt to insert the info into the database. It just sits in the form entry, whereas inserting a QR scan and hitting enter will add it to our database.

Comment: It would be cleaner to test the ubound of fValue and run two different insert SQL statments based on that.

Comment: So you're saying don't define each array value? Just keep the "fValue = Split(Me.txtScanArea.Value, ",")" statement? I still wouldn't know how to split this up into two different insert statements. In other words, what would differentiate one from the other. I hope this makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim SQL1 As String, SQL2 As String, fValue

SQL1 = "INSERT INTO dbo_ScanLog (Lot, Type, " & _
      "Serial, ScanName, ScanProcess, ScanLot, Expired, " & _
      "Weight, SPN, ScanWarning, Loc, Category, ScanCount, ScanDate) " & _
      "VALUES"

fValue = Split(Me.txtScanArea.Value, ",")

If UBound(fValue) = 0 Then      '2d barcode
    SQL2 = "('" & fValue(0) & "',null, null, null " 'etc etc
ElseIf UBound(fValue) = 5 Then  'QR with 6 values
    SQL2 = "('" & fValue(0) & "',' & fvalue(1) ','" & fValue(2) & "'," 'etc etc
Else
    MsgBox "Unknown scan format!"
    Exit Sub
End If

InsertDB (SQL1 & SQL2)
```

Using parameters would be preferable to building your SQL as a string though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Tim! UBound was exactly what I needed in this situation. Unfortunately, I had just never heard of it before. Thanks for your quick responses!

I did actually get it to work using an If statement using the Len function, but UBound is more exact in this case.

I ultimately went with and If Else statement. Ex: "If UBound(fValue) > 1 Then" followed by a SQL statement, "Else" followed by another SQL statement with blank values ('').